# Orchard CMS 1.6.1. slow to load pages (Azure)

Tags: .net, azure, orchardcms

I am developing a big project on Orchard CMS. I decided to create simple promo site (without my modules) based on Orchard while developing the project. I've successfully deployed Orchard into Azure, installed necessary modules and created all pages. Site has been working fine for a few weeks. And then the problems started.

Someday I saw that CPU's quota is exceeded. Log file was clear. There wasn't any requests to the site, except search bots. All my attempts to find a reason have failed. After that I disable a couple of modules: Cache - 1.3 and Combinator.

After few days I got a new problem. I don't know why, but Orchard tried to recompile some module and could not to save them to FS Storage (storage was busy or something like that). This problem was easily solved.

And now there is another problem. Each request to the site is taking about 30 seconds to display. In azure dashboard I see, that there are some background process in Orchard, which spends about 50% CPU's quota. Log file is clear. There is not any additional modules, except Vandelay Industries and Advanced Sitemap. And I don't know how detect what is wrong.
I tried to set log level ALL. After 5 minutes there was 10mb log file with NHibirnate records.

How can I solve that problem? It is normal to Orchard always to change somethings (eg. rebuild modules)?

Comment: Similar issue with Orchard 1.6 on Windows Azure. Haven't tried to troubleshoot, just dropped it :(

Comment: This is being worked on by the Azure team. It's a problem that is apparently not Orchard-specific.

Comment: I suppose there is some error in one of modules. And I haven't any ideas who I can detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just experienced this problem this last Friday.  My solution was to deploy my Orchard site to Amazon EC2 and call it a day.

I was using azure web sites, not web roles.  Web sites is currently in "preview".  So, I guess I can't expect that to work.   Note:  I did try "backing" my website with a reserved small instance as well.  That didn't cause any performance increase AT ALL.

So, I opened a ticket with Microsoft Support saying it ran very fast locally, they responded with it being a configuration issue with Orchard!  So, at that point I created the EC2 instance and provided Microsoft support the URL to my EC2 instance and asked them why the identical configuration on EC2 runs soooooo fast!

I am planning to try and deploy to an azure web role instead of a web site, but at the moment I'm just disenchanted with Microsoft's answer and of course have other tasks to complete..  I'll hopefully find time to give a web role a shot in a few days.

RANT: The EC2 Free instance ran out of disk space before I even installed the .NET Framework!!! So, it seems one can't run an ASP.NET web site for free on Amazon.. at least not without getting really creative..  Minimum disk space required for Server 2012 32 GB:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134246.aspx, and the EC2 instance only had 30GB..